# k-Nearest-Neighbor on a column

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, nearest-neighbor

I have a dataset with a row that has unknowns which I thought I could use k-Nearest Neighbor on. When I read through the description of the function `knnimpute` in Matlab it says that it replaces the NaN values with their closest neighbor column value. So I did a transpose on that column so all of the data is now in a single row. However, I get an error saying all the rows have NaN values in them. So I am a bit confused as to how to go about it.

Here's the code I ran:

```
knnimp = knnimpute(transpose(ds.stage),k);
```

I couldn't put a screen shot of the data but here's what it looks like (all of the data is in a row):

```
1 2 4 3 2 1 1 NaN 3 3 3 1 NaN 2 NaN
```

Here's the output I get after running the code on the transposed data:

```
All rows of the input data contains missing values. Unable to impute missing values.
```

Comment: Hard to guess the reason for the problem. Can you please post a minimal example: a dataset, your command, the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the looks of it you are running k-nearest neighbour on a single vector of data; that is a set of samples with only a single feature each.

Looking at example 1 on the [method documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/bioinfo/ref/knnimpute.html), it expects a matrix in which each column is a sample, and each row is a feature. It seems the technique used to fill in missing nan values only works if there are multiple features for each sample (i.e.: if you are passing in a matrix).

As you are passing a vector (i.e. multiple samples and a single feature) the algorithm cannot fill in the NaNs, so you would have to remove them before applying the k-nearest neighbour function.

Something like:

```
temp_stage = ds.stage(~isnan(ds.stage));
knnimp = knnimpute(transpose(temp_stage),k);
```

Comment: What i actually wanted is to estimate a value for the NANs using the nearest neighbour as opposed to taking out the NaNs completely because there are other features in the dataset that i need to do bayes classfication on, including ds.stage as one attributes for the classification

Comment: The problem is that you are not giving the the algorithm anything to make the estimate with. I think you will need to involve the other features in the dataset; what are they?

Answer (score 0):

Even with a matrix as an argument, the knnimpute function throws the error message if every row of the matrix has at least one missing element. I am not sure how this constraint (having rows with no missing element) can generally be met. This is equivalent to expecting a data set with no missing values for one or more of the features.

[Example:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUKyT.png)